# MediaRecorder.start() failing without errors on Ios Chrome and Safari. Working on desktop chrome / ff

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I have a mobile website that takes a few pictures (environment cam) and records a short video (user cam). On desktop, everything works fine. On mobile, the camera feed is shown on both chrome and Safari. Taking pictures also works, but when I try to start recording, the page does not execute any javascript code after mediarecorder.start(1000). This means instructions are not shown and the vid never stops recording.

Code:

```
async function start() 
        {
          var constraints = { video: { width: { ideal: 4096 }, height: { ideal: 2160 }, facingMode: 'user'}};
            
            cameraStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
            video.srcObject = cameraStream;  video.play();
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(cameraStream,{ mimeType: 'video/webm' });
            mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function(e) {
                    chunks.push(e.data);
    
                });
        }
        function startRecording() 
        {
          console.log("starting recording")
            takePicture();
            console.log("Selfie taken")
            outline.style.display = 'none';
            button.style.display = 'none';
            text.innerText = "Volg de instructies op het scherm.";
            //WORKS FINE TILL HERE
            mediaRecorder.start(1000);
            //BELOW THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED
            console.log("setting timeout");
            setTimeout(step,2000);

        }
```

As said, it works on desktop, but not on iOS chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari on iOS are unfortunately more or less the same. Apple only allows their own browser engine on iOS and Chrome plays by those rules.

The `MediaRecorder` in Safari doesn't support `'video/webm'` which is why I guess there is already an error thrown when you construct the `MediaRecorder`. Consequently the `mediaRecorder` variable is undefined when you try to call `start()` later on.

It probably works if you let Safari (or Chrome on iOS) pick the mimeType itself by omitting the configuration.

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(cameraStream);
```